# How to raise an exception in the init method for a CPython module

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython, python-internals

I am writing a `CPython` extension on top of a library that was written in `C` and I couldn't find a solution on how to raise an exception in the `init` method. So, I split it up and, basically, the constructor will save the attributes to the object and then you have to call an init method `mr.initialize()`.

I find this method a bit ugly, and I want to find a solution to raise a `ValueError` exception in the constructor, here is my current code:

```
static int libzihc_MRLoader_init(libzihc_MRLoader *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
    double error_rate;
    const char *in;
    unsigned int capacity;

    static char *kwlist[] = {"in", NULL};
    if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, kwds, "s", kwlist, &in)) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (self->dataPath) {
        free(self->dataPath);
    }
    self->dataPath = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(in)+1));
    if (self->dataPath) {
        strcpy(self->dataPath, in);
    } else {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the added initialize method like so:

```
static PyObject* initialize(libzihc_MRLoader *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
    const char * msgError = NULL;
    int status = openRes(self->dataPath, &(self->ienaKey), &msgError);

    if(status != 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, msgError);
        printf("openRes returns %d\n",  status);
        return (PyObject *) NULL;
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("i", status);
}
```

From the `CPython` doc, if you want the interpreter to raise the exception you need to call one of the methods used to raise an exception in my case I use `PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, msgError)`, and return `null`.

In this case the init method in `CPython` have to be `static int`, so I cannot return `null`, I did, however, remove the `return` statement, I saw the exception in `stdout`, but the interpreter did not stop.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Relevant thing you might like: https://llllllllll.github.io/c-extension-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a negative value in `libzihc_MRLoader_init`, usually `-1` for Python to catch it, search if an exception is set and end execution. At least, that's what [`type_call`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l762) checks for after calling an objects `__init__` method:

```C
    type = obj->ob_type;
    if (PyType_HasFeature(type, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_CLASS) &&
        type->tp_init != NULL &&
        type->tp_init(obj, args, kwds) < 0) {  // if res < 0 returns NULL
        Py_DECREF(obj);
        obj = NULL;
    }
```

So, in your specific case, you can move the code from `initialize` in `libzihc_MRLoader_init` and, if an error has occurred, return `-1` instead of `null` to signal it.

Comment: thanks @Jim for your response, but if I don't return `null` the interpreter will not catch the Exception and it will not stop the execution.

Comment: @e-nouri I was suggesting returning `-1` in `libzihc_MRLoader_init` in which you cannot return `null`, not in `initialize`.

Comment: thank you, I should tryed that before even posting here, but the doc was not very clear on how to stop the interpreter after calling the PyErr_* functions.

Comment: @e-nouri you should always give a shot at finding similar examples in [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/) for `Python 2`. It's readable and in most cases you'll learn more in the process.